Using Azure Text Analytics to Detect Language per Sentence Instead of Paragraph
I am new to Azure. I want to use Azure AI's language detection service, which I have set up using the following code on my local machine:
def authenticate_client():
    endpoint = os.environ["AZURE_LANGUAGE_ENDPOINT"]
    key = os.environ["AZURE_LANGUAGE_KEY"]
    ta_credential = AzureKeyCredential(key)
    text_analytics_client = TextAnalyticsClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=ta_credential)
    return text_analytics_client

def detect_language(texts):
    client = authenticate_client()
    try:
        response = client.detect_language(documents=texts) #, country_hint='us')
        results = []
        for idx, doc in enumerate(response):
            if not doc.is_error:
                results.append({
                    "Document": texts[idx],
                    "Language": doc.primary_language.name,
                    "ISO6391 Name": doc.primary_language.iso6391_name,
                    "Confidence Score": doc.primary_language.confidence_score
                })
            else:
                results.append({
                    "Document": texts[idx],
                    "Error": doc.error.message
                })
        return results

    except Exception as err:
        print("Encountered exception:", err)
        return []
example_texts = [
    "The employee's SSN is 859-98-0987. My name is John."
]
results = detect_language(example_texts)
for r in results:
    print(r)

output:
{'Document': "The employee's SSN is 859-98-0987. My name is John.", 'Language': 'English', 'ISO6391 Name': 'en', 'Confidence Score': 1.0}

Now, I want to adjust the code to use textSplitMode="sentences" to detect the language of each sentence instead of each paragraph. I have tried various methods to implement this using the textSplitMode parameter, but it hasn't been successful. I understand that I could create a custom function for this purpose, but I prefer to utilize Azure services for now.
For reference, here is the documentation path to the Text Split cognitive skill in Azure:
[text](Now, I want to adjust the code to use textSplitMode="sentences" to detect the language of each sentence instead of each paragraph. I have tried various methods to implement this using the textSplitMode parameter, but it hasn't been successful. I understand that I could create a custom function for this purpose, but I prefer to utilize Azure services for now.
For reference, here is the documentation path to the Text Split cognitive skill in Azure:Now, I want to adjust the code to use textSplitMode="sentences" to detect the language of each sentence instead of each paragraph. I have tried various methods to implement this using the textSplitMode parameter, but it hasn't been successful. I understand that I could create a custom function for this purpose, but I prefer to utilize Azure services for now.
For reference, here is the documentation path to the Text Split cognitive skill in Azure:)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-textsplit


Is my solution helpful to you?

Text Split cognitive skill in Azure is not what you are thinking
Please follow this documentation to understand what azure ai search actually is.
But if you wish to combine both the services possible approach is below.
Create an ai search service with your document and add the text split skill where you will get the data of in the array then fetch that data and detect language for each sentence.
After you are creating the ai search and mapping the output fields of text split skill results you can use this python code to fetch the data
Sample
# Run an empty query (returns selected fields, all documents)
results =  search_client.search(query_type='simple',
    search_text="*" ,
    include_total_count=True)

print ('Total Documents Matching Query:', results.get_count())
for result in results:
    print(result["TextItems"]) #which you got output from split skill.

Then loop through this results and detect language.
Actually you have to do lot more things like i have mentioned above in simple words, that is the reason i have asked you to look more about azure ai search what is it used actually.
Or you have to use separate function to split you text.
Here is the sample one using nltk.
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

example_texts = [
    data1
]

results = {}
for i,d in enumerate(example_texts):
    results[f"doc_{i}"] = detect_language(sent_tokenize(d))

Using nltk splitting is done for each document and send to detect language.
Sample output:
{'doc_0': [{'Document': '\nI am new to Azure.',
   'Language': 'English',
   'ISO6391 Name': 'en',
   'Confidence Score': 1.0},
  {'Document': 'I want to use Azure AI\'s language detection service, which I have set up using the following code on my local machine:\n\ndef authenticate_client():\n    endpoint = os.environ["AZURE_LANGUAGE_ENDPOINT"]\n    key = os.environ["AZURE_LANGUAGE_KEY"]\n    ta_credential = AzureKeyCredential(key)\n    text_analytics_client = TextAnalyticsClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=ta_credential)\n    return text_analytics_client\n\ndef detect_language(texts):\n    client = authenticate_client()\n    try:\n        response = client.detect_language(documents=texts) #, country_hint=\'us\')\n        results = []\n        for idx, doc in enumerate(response):\n            if not doc.is_error:\n                results.append({\n                    "Document": texts[idx],\n                    "Language": doc.primary_language.name,\n                    "ISO6391 Name": doc.primary_language.iso6391_name,\n                    "Confidence Score": doc.primary_language.confidence_score\n                })\n            else:\n                results.append({\n                    "Document": texts[idx],\n                    "Error": doc.error.message\n                })\n        return results\n\n    except Exception as err:\n        print("Encountered exception:", err)\n        return []\nexample_texts = [\n    "The employee\'s SSN is 859-98-0987.',
   'Language': 'English',
   'ISO6391 Name': 'en',
   'Confidence Score': 1.0},
  {'Document': 'My name is John."',
   'Language': 'English',
   'ISO6391 Name': 'en',
   'Confidence Score': 1.0},

For each document the list of sentence and detected language is output.
